# Protecting (encrypting) system from even root access

Tags: linux, encryption, luks

I plan to provide a Linux appliance to several users.  These users are tech savvy and can easily reset the root password on a standard linux system.

How can I create a running Linux system that keeps even the root user out of the filesystem once protected?  (I looked at disk encryption like LUKS but in all cases the root user can gain access to an automounted partition).

How do I solve this problem?  Stack exchange questions like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71015/protecting-file-system-contents-with-tpm-and-encrypted-file-system) assume the attacker does NOT have root access, but it seems simple to reset root password by booting into single user/recovery mode.

I've read about LUKS but FDE requires rolling the keyfile into the initramfs (as shown [here](https://dradisframework.com/support/guides/customization/auto-unlock-luks-encrypted-drive.html)) but I think you can easily unroll the initramfs and extract the key.  So I don't think this solves the problem

Comment: This appliance would boot and run without user intervention, so I assume keys are stored somewhere on the disk (I have not used LUKS before).  Can they not interrupt bootup at some point if keys are on the fully encrypted disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: encrypt the full disk with LUKS, then store the keys in the system TPM.  That way the entire disk is encrypted and an end user can't extract the keys from the TPM...very secure:

[LUKS with TPM](https://github.com/fox-it/linux-luks-tpm-boot)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is **not** possible to reset the root password on a PC with full disk encryption (FDE).

The tutorial linked in that answer you added talks about automounting some non-system drive. With FDE everything below `/` is encrypted including `/root/keyfile`.

If you put the keyfile to your system partition on a non-encrypted partition (e.g. `/boot`) for convenience reasons, your friends will be able to read the file, so don't do this.

Read:

- [How secure is Ubuntu's default full-disk encryption?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39306/how-secure-is-ubuntus-default-full-disk-encryption)
- [How secure is an encrypted LUKS filesystem?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97196/how-secure-is-an-encrypted-luks-filesystem)

---

Regarding the addition from your comment:

*"This appliance would boot and run without user intervention"*:

Do not allow untrusted users to boot your computer.  If users can boot from your encrypted hard drive they either know the password or have an unencrypted keyfile for the encryption and then they can do whatever they want with the computer.

Keep the computer booted, or have some trusted users than are allowed to boot.

Comment: The second part of the comments would defeat what I am trying to achieve.  I need to ship an appliance to a customer, so they will boot/reboot the device as needed.  Clicking through several links I found reference to rolling the keyfile into the boot image - but I thought that can be unrolled too?

Comment: I'm not sure this answer really addresses how to prevent access the file system from even the root user.  (Or could you clarify)

Comment: It is not possible to prevent access if you don't use FDE. Using FDE with unencrypted keyfile is like not using FDE. That is what I mean when I said "*they can do whatever they want with the computer.*".